# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created in to-do app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sveltekit

I have been writing a basic to-do app in SvelteKit with Firebase. No problems appear in VScode, but in the console on my website I get this issue:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE9Da.png)

```
+layout.svelte:41 [HMR][Svelte] Unrecoverable HMR error in <+page>: next update will trigger a full reload
```

and

```
firebase_firestore.js?v=c42495b4:277 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (firebase_firestore.js?v=c42495b4:277:25)
    at getFirestore (firebase_firestore.js?v=c42495b4:16709:41)
    at instance (+page.svelte:17:25)
    at init (chunk-K76FTQQM.js?v=c42495b4:2190:23)
    at new Page (+page.svelte:67:25)
    at createProxiedComponent (svelte-hooks.js?v=c42495b4:341:9)
    at new ProxyComponent (proxy.js?v=c42495b4:242:7)
    at new Proxy<+page> (proxy.js?v=c42495b4:349:11)
    at construct_svelte_component_dev (chunk-K76FTQQM.js?v=c42495b4:2634:22)
    at Array.create_default_slot (root.svelte:45:82)
```

This is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
  import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,
    onSnapshot,
    query,
  } from "firebase/firestore";
  import { firebaseConfig } from "$lib/firebaseConfig";
  import { browser } from "$app/environment";

  // some weird stuff for making firebase work with sveltekit on the server side
  const firebaseApp =
    browser &&
    (getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp());

  const db = browser && getFirestore();

  const colRef = browser && db && collection(db, "todos");

  let todos: Todo[] = [];

  const todosQuery = browser && colRef && query(colRef);

  const abc =
    browser &&
    todosQuery &&
    onSnapshot(todosQuery, (querySnapshot: any) => {
      let fbTodos: Todo[] = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
        let todo = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
        fbTodos = [todo, ...fbTodos];
      });
      todos = fbTodos;
    });

  console.log({ firebaseApp, db });

  interface Todo {
    task: string;
    isComplete: boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
  }

  let task = "";

  const addTodo = () => {
    let todo = {
      task: task,
      isComplete: false,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    };
    todos = [todo, ...todos];
    task = "";
  };

  const markTodoAsComplete = (index: number) => {
    todos[index].isComplete = !todos[index].isComplete;
  };

  const deleteTodo = (index: number) => {
    let deleteItem = todos[index];
    let newTodos = todos.filter((item) => item != deleteItem);
    todos = newTodos;
  };

  $: console.table(todos);
</script>

<form class="search-form" on:submit={addTodo}>
  <input
    class="search-field"
    type="text"
    bind:value={task}
    placeholder="Add a task"
  />
  <input type="submit" value="+" />
</form>

<ol>
  {#each todos as item, index}
    <li class:complete={item.isComplete}>
      <span>
        {item.task}
      </span>
      <span>
        <button on:click={() => markTodoAsComplete(index)}>✅</button>
        <button on:click={() => deleteTodo(index)}>️</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  {:else}
    <p>No tasks right now.</p>
  {/each}
</ol>

<style>
  .complete {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
</style>
```

ChatGPT has't helped, and I haven't been able to solve the problem on my own, as I am very new to SvelteKit and Firebase. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling `getFirestore()` without making sure that firebase has indeed been initialized. You could solve it by doing:

```
imports...

const firebaseApp = ...

$: if (firebaseApp) {
    ...initialize the rest here:
        db, colRef, todos, etc.
}
```

https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive